# Who are the white titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the latest trailer of the attack on titan (4th season), we saw white titans who have weapons and fight with each other.

My question is who are they? Are they titans that armored? Are they enemies with each other?

[image: white titan 1] [image: white titan 2]

Comment: You can eventually find this out after reading the manga or waiting for the final season...And also, it's not 'they' since there's only one War Hammer Titan.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching finally, I found the answer.

The real name of this white titan is the ***War Hammer Titan***.

> The War Hammer is one of the [Nine Titans](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Nine_Titans), and it possesses the
>   ability to create structures out of hardened Titan flesh. Until the
>   year 854, it was kept within the Tybur family for generations. It is
>   currently in the possession of Eren Yeager.

[image]

Remember the Se03-Ep08 when Eren creates a cage to protect the Scouts. That structured cage was because of this ability of Eren.

[image]

For more information about this type of titan check [this](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/War_Hammer_Titan), but be aware of spoiler warning.

Comment: Actually, I do remember that Eren had to take a vial of some liquid right before using that ability, plus Annie was also able to encase herself in a similar structure. I was under the impression that all Titans could use that hardenning ability. Guess we'll find out in the next season